# can glusterfs and glusterfs_registry share same nodes/devices

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, okd

Can i configure same nodes for glusterfs and glusterfs_registry group like below or they should have different nodes in group?

```
[glusterfs]
node1  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]'
node2  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]' 
node3  glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]' 

[glusterfs_registry]
node1    glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]'
node2    glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]' 
node3    glusterfs_devices='[ "/dev/vdb" ]'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs it is not suggested to do so:
https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_glusterfs.html#considerations-hardware-prereqs

I also think that the ansible installer would have a problem with it.

But probably give the CIC tool a try: https://github.com/red-hat-storage/openshift-cic
I didn't so far and we installed our cluster with 6 storage nodes, 3 for each type.